# Selecting from one table, where the ID from another table can be found in a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I'm currently trying to select all data from one table, where the ID matches the ID in a second table, where the IDs from the second table match an ID in the third table.

I would only like to return data, where the IDs in table two can be found in the third table.

There may be duplicates coming through on the ID, hence I was trying to use MIN in my code below, but this yielded no results.

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 one
LEFT JOIN T2 two ON two.ID = one.ID
WHERE two.ID IN 
(SELECT min(ID)
FROM T3 three)) abc
```

Comment: A [mcve] would make it eaiser to assist!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify what you want to do.  Your first two paragraphs don't seem to be describing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 1-1 relationship between `t1` and `t2` and a 1-N relationship between `t1` and `t3`, I think that you want `exists`:

```
SELECT t1.ID 
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t3
    WHERE t3.ID = t1.ID
)
```

The advantage of exists is that it does not duplicate rows if there is more than one record in `t3` with a matching `ID`.

Note: if you want only rows where `ID`s match, then you want an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`. The former eliminates non-matching records, while the latter allows them.

Answer (score 0):

The code below selects all records from Table one which have matching Ids to the ones in Table two and Table three

```
SELECT * 
FROM   t1 one 
       JOIN (SELECT two.* 
             FROM   t2 two 
                    JOIN t3 three 
                      ON two.id = three.id) t 
         ON one.id = t.id
```